# How to get face normals average in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I generally program Unity3D related stuff, I'm still pretty new to Maya's python API.

What I'm trying to do is to get the currently selected face normals average:

[image: What I need to achieve]

What I achieved until now is an instance of a cube positioned according to the Move Manipulator.

[image: Code result]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import re #regular expression

# get current position of the move manipulator
pos = cmds.manipMoveContext('Move', q=True, p=True)

# get the current selection
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)

# trying to get the face normal angles of the current selection
polyInfo = cmds.polyInfo(selection, fn=True)
polyInfoArray = re.findall(r"[\w.-]+", polyInfo[0]) # convert the string to array with regular expression
polyInfoX = float(polyInfoArray[2])
polyInfoY = float(polyInfoArray[3])
polyInfoZ = float(polyInfoArray[4])

print str(polyInfoX) + ', ' + str(polyInfoY) + ', ' + str(polyInfoZ)

target = cmds.polyCube()

cmds.move(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], target)
```

Now what I only need is to rotate the cube to the face average normals of the selection

Please, any thoughts about this?

Maya does have any method to give me those angles? I tried to rotate using polyInfo with face normals, but I think I'm missing something...

EDIT:

The final solution (thanks to @theodox)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# get current position of the move manipulator
pos = cmds.manipMoveContext('Move', query=True, position=True) 

# get the current selection
selection = cmds.ls(selection=True)

target = cmds.polyCube()

cmds.move(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], target)

constr = cmds.normalConstraint(selection, target, aimVector = (0,0,1), worldUpType= 0)
cmds.delete(constr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want without solving the issue in the question. The `normalConstraint` node will orient an object towards the closest available face normal. If you just want the face alignment, you can position your object and then create and immediately delete a normalConstraint. A minimal version would be:

```
 constr = cmds.normalConstraint('reference_object', 
                                'object_to_align', 
                                 aimVector = (0,0,1),
                                 worldUpType= 0)
 cmds.delete(constr)
```

where the aim vector is the local axis that will be aligned to the surface. (There are a lot of options for how to do the alignment, you should check the docs in the normalConstraint command for more).

To actually get the face normal, you can use the `polyNormalPerVertex` command to get the vertex-face normals for a face (they'll come back as numbers so you don't need to regex it. You will need to average them:

```
def face_normal(face):
    vtxface = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(face, tvf = True)
    xes = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex(vtxface, q=True, x =True)
    yes = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex(vtxface, q=True, y =True)
    zes = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex(vtxface, q=True, z =True)
    divisor = 1.0 / len(xes)
    return sum(xes)* divisor, sum(yes)  * divisor, sum(zes) * divisor
```

However those are in *local space*. The only way to convert them to world space is to turn them into a vector (using Pymel or the Maya api) and then multiply them against the object matrix (also using the API). Once you have a world space vector you can construct a new matrix using that vector as the 'aim vector', the world up, and the cross vector of those as a new matrix for the object you want to align..

... all of which is not *super* hard but it's a lot of work if you don't know the API well yet. Which is why I'd try the normalConstraint trick first.

Comment: Many thanks @theodox!! The normal constraint solved my problem like a charm, thanks for the alternative!